# React Native unable to pod install Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

During the Invertase Firebase Crashlytics setup (https://rnfirebase.io/crashlytics/ios-setup) , I continuously get the the following error:

```
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Crashlytics"
```

Or other variant relating to `Firebase/Core` or `Firebase/CoreOnly`

**Podfile**

```
pod 'Firebase/Core'
pod 'Firebase/CoreOnly'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Crashlytics'
```

Even if I try to set each package to a specific version with `~> 6.x.x`

**related node modules**

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.7.1",
"@react-native-firebase/crashlytics": "^6.7.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^5.1.6",
```

Comment: react-native-firebase supports lib auto-link, which means you don't need to add Firebase pods in Podfile manually.

Comment: You can try removing Podfile.lock and then try again if it works.

Answer (score 0):

> react-native-firebase supports lib auto-link, which means you don't need to add
>   Firebase pods in Podfile manually

**duan** response worked for me, at least i have no errors
also, i linked this manually:

```
react-native link @react-native-firebase/crashlytics
```